# what is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}=\{(i,j):i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$  and we can think two equivalence classes namely;$$c_1=\{(i,0):i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ and $$c_2=\{(0,i):i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ such that $$c-c'\in\mathbb{Z}\ \forall c,c'\in c_{1}$$ and $$c-c'\in\mathbb{Z}\ \forall c,c'\in c_{2}$$ thus
$$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}=\{[c_1],[c_2]\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not make sense to quotient a group by another abstract group. What makes sense is to quotient by a *subgroup*. In other words, the writing $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}$ makes no sense if you don't precise how you embed $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Which subgroup you are looking at.

If your embedding is $n\mapsto (n,0)$ then the answer will be $\mathbb{Z}$. If your embedding is $n\mapsto (2n,0)$ then the answer will be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, etc.

Comment: I don't know rings by $\mathbb{Z}$ i mean additive cyclic group.

Comment: @physshyp I edited accordingly. The answer is the exact same for groups and for rings in this case.

Comment: I am not familiar with the embeding, since I just starting to learn group theory, however I have encountered with  this calculation in this context https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647361/unclear-step-on-the-calculation-of-a-homology-group.

Comment: The link you give sends to a question in homology, with simplicial complexes and thus also algebraic topology. How in the world are you studying this **and also** "starting to to learn group theory"?? This sounds to me like trying to climb the Everest while being in Washington D.C. ...

Answer (score 1):

$c_1$ and $c_2$ cannot be equivalence classes for any equivalence relation as they are not disjoint: $(0,0)\in c_1\cap c_2$.

Also they don't cover $\mathbb{Z}^2$: Which class does $(1,1)$ belong to?

Comment: I see you are rigth.

Comment: so is it just isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: As Arnaud mentioned the quotient $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ is not well-defined without specifying the embedding $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ and it certainly depends on such an embedding.